# What is wrong with the implementation of my DoubleLinkedList?

Tags: java, data-structures, doubly-linked-list

I am currently learning Data Structures and Algorithm and one of the exercises was to implement a DoublyLinkedList from scratch. Unfortunately when i try to perform the **"listDelete"** operation on my list, my code works well for some integer values and not for some. It works fine when I try to delete *23, 45, 100, 5, 15*. There is an [Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NRXo.png) when i try to delete *400* from the list.

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * Created on 13-Aug-16.
 */
public class DoublyLinkedList<Item> implements Iterable<Item>{
    private Node<Item> head ;

    private class Node<Item>{
        private Item key;
        private Node<Item> prev;
        private Node<Item> next;
    }

    public Node<Item> listSearch(Item key)
    {
        Node<Item> currentNode = head ;

        while (currentNode != null && currentNode.key != key)
                currentNode = currentNode.next ;

        return currentNode ;
    }

    public void listInsert(Item item)
    {
        Node<Item> newNode = new Node<>();  //create an object of incoming item
        newNode.next = head ;
        newNode.prev = null ;
        newNode.key = item ;

        if (head != null)
            head.prev = newNode ;

        head = newNode;
    }

    public void listDelete(Item item){
        Node<Item> nodeToDelete = listSearch(item);

        if (nodeToDelete == null)
            throw new NoSuchElementException("Cant find element");

        if(nodeToDelete.prev != null)
            nodeToDelete.prev.next = nodeToDelete.next ;
        else
            head = nodeToDelete.next;

        if (nodeToDelete.next != null)
            nodeToDelete.next.prev = nodeToDelete.prev ;
    }

    public Iterator<Item> iterator(){
        return new DoublyLinkedListIterator();
    }

    private class DoublyLinkedListIterator implements Iterator<Item>{
        private Node<Item> nextNode;

        public DoublyLinkedListIterator(){
            nextNode = head;
        }

        public boolean hasNext(){
            return nextNode != null ;
        }

        public Item next(){
            if (!hasNext())
                throw new NoSuchElementException();

            Item key = nextNode.key;

            nextNode = nextNode.next ;

            return key;
        }

        public void remove(){
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
    } //end of Iterator class

    public String toString(){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for(Item item : this)
            sb.append(item + ", ");

        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DoublyLinkedList<Integer> numbers = new DoublyLinkedList<>();

        Random random = new Random();

        numbers.listInsert(23);
        for (int i=1; i <=5; i++)
            numbers.listInsert(random.nextInt(100));
        numbers.listInsert(45);
        numbers.listInsert(100);
        numbers.listInsert(400);
        numbers.listInsert(5);

       for (int i=1; i <=10; i++)
            numbers.listInsert(random.nextInt(100));
        numbers.listInsert(15);

        System.out.println("Before");
        System.out.println("LIST: " + numbers);

        System.out.println("Deleting......................");
        numbers.listDelete(100); //doesnot work for some set of integers
        System.out.println("After");
        System.out.println("LIST: " + numbers);
    }
} //end of class
```

Comment: In the future, please include exception messages in your question.

Comment: This is where using the debugger in your IDE is likely to help you find the bug faster than asking of SO. If you are not familiar with your debugger, I highly recommend you learn to use it, it will save you hours and days of wasted time.

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask),and [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). **SO is not a free coding, debugging or homework completion service.** You have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem and ask a specific question.

Comment: Try to specify your doubts precisely....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using generic data type (Item) here, so while comparing two elements you should use equals method rather than using reference (==)

```
public Node<Item> listSearch(Item key)
    {
        Node<Item> currentNode = head ;   
        while (currentNode != null && !currentNode.key.equals(key))
                currentNode = currentNode.next ;
        return currentNode ;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Sandeep. Your answer fixed it.